# Running python script from matlab not working, but runs fine from terminal

Tags: python, matlab, system

I have a python script say script.py that I can call from the terminal no problem, in the middle of the script it unarchives a file using `os.system('unar file')`.  However, when trying to run this script from matlab using `system('python script.py')` it runs, but then when it gets to the unar line, it states "sh:unar: command not found".

How is this possible? Isn't the matlab system command supposed to be the same as the terminal?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if MATLAB doesn't initialize your `$PATH` the same as a shell would.  Does running `echo $PATH` from the terminal produce the same output as running `system('echo $PATH')` from inside MATLAB?  Also of note is that MATLAB appears to be using `sh` instead of bash, although I don't think that should be a problem in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your terminal, your python script get to benefit from your `PATH` environment, so it knows where the `/usr/bin/unar` application is located. Within Matlab, it doesn't. You need to give your `os.system` call the full path to both your application, and your file.

Also, os.system is pretty awful. Use `subprocess.Popen` instead, which allows redirection of `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout`.

Here's a gist example using `subprocess`: https://gist.github.com/voodoonofx/8e5bcae8e0b0c5741148

Comment: This worked great! I did change from unar to 7za since unar was not in /usr/bin/unar but 7za was.